# VBS script fails to run when called as a Scheduled Task in Windows 8

Tags: post, vbscript, windows-8, scheduled-tasks

I have created a VBS script that runs perfectly fine when manually run on Windows 8 Home computers even on IDs that have no admin rights. This same script fails repeatedly no matter what user credentials I've used to run it through a scheduled task on computer start up. I've tried the system, admin, and unprivileged user IDs that are on the machine all with no success.

This same VBS script has no issues at all being run from a scheduled task on multiple Windows 7, and Windows 8.1 Home and Professional machines.

This script attempts to successfully ping a website, and upon successful ping will POST data to the web page with the current time of the local computer.

```
boolExitFlag = False

Do
    If Ping("HOSTNAME") Then
        Call pingsuccess              
        boolExitFlag = True
    End If
        WScript.sleep 1000
Loop while boolExitFlag <> True

Sub pingsuccess
    set oHTTP = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    oHTTP.open "POST", "URL",false
    oHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    oHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Length", Len("send=send&time=" & Hour(Now) & ":" & Minute(Now) & ":" & Second(Now))
    oHTTP.send "send=send&time=" & Hour(Now) & ":" & Minute(Now) & ":" & Second(Now)
End Sub

Function Ping(strHost)
    Dim oPing, oRetStatus, bReturn
    Set oPing = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}").ExecQuery("select * from Win32_PingStatus where address='" & strHost & "'")

    For Each oRetStatus In oPing
        If IsNull(oRetStatus.StatusCode) Or oRetStatus.StatusCode <> 0 Then
            bReturn = False
        Else
            bReturn = True
        End If
        Set oRetStatus = Nothing
    Next
    Set oPing = Nothing

    Ping = bReturn
End Function
```

When the scheduled task is run on the Windows 8 machines I see
"The task is currently running. (0x41301)" with no success. I have tried nearly EVERYTHING to attempt to get this working outside of writing a batch script to run the VBS script. That just seems excessively unnecessary though.

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I could manage to get Windows 8 to run this VBS script was to create a batch file that called the VBS, and checked the box in the scheduled task to "Run with highest privileges". Without both the script would not run. I am not 100% sure why only Windows 8 fails miserably without doing this.

The batch file contained only the following code.

```
start "" "C:\path\to\script.vbs"
```

Comment: This solution STILL does not work in Windows 8 if the computer is turned on from a cold boot. If restarted, the script runs without a problem.... what gives??